# Profiling on Hexagon DSP

Tags: hexagon-dsp

I want to profile code on Hexagon Dsp using sysMon_DSP_profiler nad i have installed it but it is continously crashing .Is there any solution to this problem or any other method to do profiling on target.

Comment: How does it crash?  Can you get a stack trace?

Comment: When am opening app in android it is crashing.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the code being profiled, it may be easier for you to use the DSP simulator to do the profiling.  This answer has a reference to the manual for using `hexagon-sim` with `hexagon-profiler`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50126010/489590

Comment: yeah but i have used the method you preferred but iam getting the cycles that seems to be very less.For calculation of MCPS i need to multiply with clock frequecy of DSP.If thats the case ,Whats the clock frequecy of HeXAGON dsp.